# Spring and Junit test initializationError

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, spring-test

I'm new with JUnit and Spring test, I created a class like this (only for start to try the test code):

```
package com.dao;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.config.core.AppConfig;
import com.domain.Building;
import com.domain.City;
import com.services.dbservices.tables.BuildingServices;
import com.services.dbservices.tables.CityServices;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class })
@Transactional
public class TestBuildingServices {

    protected static final Integer BUILDING_FIRST_ID = 1;
    @Autowired
    private BuildingServices buildingServices;
    @Autowired
    private CityServices cityServices;

    @Test
    @Rollback(true)
    public void testAddBuilding(){
        City city = new City("England", "En", "London");
        cityServices.create(city);
        Building  building = new Building("Street address", 1, new BigDecimal(10.55), new BigDecimal(11.07), true, city);
        buildingServices.create(building);
        Building retrievedBulding = buildingServices.findById(building.getIdBuilding());
        Assert.assertEquals(building.getCity(), retrievedBulding.getCity());
        Assert.assertEquals(building.getIdBuilding(), retrievedBulding.getIdBuilding());
    }
}
```

When I run this class as JUnite test I receive this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [null]. Specify @BootstrapWith's 'value' attribute or make the default bootstrapper class available.
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:152)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.rethrowAnnotationConfigurationException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.searchWithFindSemantics(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:1092)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.searchWithFindSemantics(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findAllMergedAnnotations(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:789)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:150)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:126)
    ... 20 more
```

I read that this is an error with Spring dependecies version but all the Spring dependencies use the same version. This is the main content of my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.jpa.version>1.11.4.RELEASE</spring.jpa.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.42</mysql.connector.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
    <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleafspringsecurity4.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</thymeleafspringsecurity4.version>
    <thymeleaflayout.version>1.3.0</thymeleaflayout.version>
    <javax.version>3.1.0</javax.version>
    <nekohtml.version>1.9.22</nekohtml.version>
    <jacksondatatype.version>2.8.9</jacksondatatype.version>
    <jacksonjsr310.version>2.7.4</jacksonjsr310.version>
    <xmlapis.version>1.4.01</xmlapis.version>

</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- database pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>${xmlapis.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>${nekohtml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleafspringsecurity4.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaflayout.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        <version>${jacksondatatype.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${jacksondatatype.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${jacksonjsr310.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        <version>${jacksondatatype.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring + aspects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORM integration, e.g Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.jpa.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- MySql Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging, slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is appConfig class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity 
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class, SpringMvcInitializer.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.repository")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";

     public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
      }


    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.findAndRegisterModules();

        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;

    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
        SpringSecurityDialect dialect = new SpringSecurityDialect();
        return dialect;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        properties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans",true);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        ds.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        ds.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        ds.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver TemplateResolver(){
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(TemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.addDialect(springSecurityDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }


    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"*", "js/*", "template/*"});
        return resolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;    
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.
                getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea of the problem?Thanks

Comment: Run Maven dependency:tree and check the Spring library versions. Your IDE should show you too if you check the jars on project classpath.

Comment: spring-test has a problem: spring-core:4.3.9.Release (omitted for conflict with 4.3.9.Release)

Comment: Find conflicting versions of Spring jars and bring them all to the same version using Maven dependency management and exclusion.

Comment: I see a lot of omitted for conflict with 4.3.9.RELEASE, only spring-test is grey and not black. Do I have to set exclusion for all these conflicts? I added a screen

Comment: Sorry, I tried to put you on the right path but I'm not gonna babysit you through this issue. Good luck.

Comment: you say what I already know. Anyway I'll continue to try to resolve. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have an exclusion for `spring-core` for the `spring-test` dependency? Those two JARs **must** be the same version, and that's actually the source of the error you're experiencing.

Comment: without exclusion I have the same error (the version is the same 4.3.9.Release)